# SHA-256 with RSA Encryption

Tags: c++, certificate, rsa, decode, sha256

I am trying to manually verify the digital signature of a self signed certificate.
SHA-256 RSA certified.

As I understand it, the digital signature is verified using the formula `s^e mod m`. At the output, I get a number of 2048 bit, and the hash itself is 256 bit. I read that it needs to be completed to 2048 bit. How is this done?

P.S.
As I understand it, I need to use the I2OSP function on the hash sum or OS2IP on the decoded number. I cannot understand the algorithm of these functions.
My numbers are stored as a byte array:
Number: 0x123456789A
Data: [0] = 9A | [1] = 78 | [2] = 56 ...
Can you write C code or at least pseudo code?

Link to certificate:
https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIDwTCCAqmgAwIBAgIQGhQKhwNj5Z5IvU4kiPIzqjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBVMVMwUQYDVQQDHkoARwBvAGwAbwB2AGwAZQB2ACAAVABpAG0AbwBmAGUAeQAgACgAVABpAG0AXwBkAGUAdgApACAAMQA1AC4AMAA1AC4AMgAwADAAMDAeFw0yMTAzMDMwMjEzNTJaFw0zOTEyMzEyMzU5NTlaMFUxUzBRBgNVBAMeSgBHAG8AbABvAHYAbABlAHYAIABUAGkAbQBvAGYAZQB5ACAAKABUAGkAbQBfAGQAZQB2ACkAIAAxADUALgAwADUALgAyADAAMAAwMIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsdIyw8JcPlDHM1fQGiBKmpWRYRhrOe31xwvYTYaQ02Uc-g0pIGzCu3Q-o6MS0i-2efIKs5shX0HFkLjMy1zgZc2F-PTx8f8HySRxroi5QVngQWLxu638sB9uYdVqBwWyNd7scZx-Z9Fd-kS0rFRIPlyuLCg8UOGtR5KbZ4V7dSNm8myHFTtVqD79n42oJEe2vkmUXQ266B2rHUdHDXJPTiXKwoZg4wAjeTkJUlgJwHeZUvpOkQfoo27C9dh8-4BRR4dHJOtwA1RDyuaVYl1tiQmBAAOcqjKf1bl9u3JLvxldIM8jura2k9oWLA3cxzx7Gr6DlIlGhD7EkyLww3n6VQIDAQABo4GMMIGJMIGGBgNVHQEEfzB9gBBOBdKqObwJh3JpHeW1T741oVcwVTFTMFEGA1UEAx5KAEcAbwBsAG8AdgBsAGUAdgAgAFQAaQBtAG8AZgBlAHkAIAAoAFQAaQBtAF8AZABlAHYAKQAgADEANQAuADAANQAuADIAMAAwADCCEBoUCocDY-WeSL1OJIjyM6owDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggEBAJeNUpwyUVqKSYGXPj6ibGfs4xxYaHf4obEJ3pgnWFblVgPahzQTutVJ5Ny-TSp0Ger8fTtu9soal35Zz9dpUE9aTYp-YWtEpaaqx5IC-OnH9Cao7ZJ_zM8fwiP9PtHNMuYCBiO24PmHF6oyB0gwcNYh0oa0YaVKJcmtHAVSH6WSzbdea3j9sdlBPVA6FeNchHCCiatesoM75IAUCvKYuBQ9JLenPvCXoKhXBDsiVb5tMKdZD8Vbvoj7b1JzKuv6NkICV99rLWW5MwfRMB-HG-BoML9E2mNJ-kqaVLFbJOZHCaNNIxejR70fY-ijexPNwvr_rI4VW01uYkdmSMlzRLE

Answer (score 1):

X.509 signatures employee padding before doing the modular exponentiation. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.2.2 describes the flow but the most relevant part is probably this:

```
   Steps:

      1.  Apply the hash function to the message M to produce a hash
          value H:

             H = Hash(M).

          If the hash function outputs "message too long", output
          "message too long" and stop.

      2.  Encode the algorithm ID for the hash function and the hash
          value into an ASN.1 value of type DigestInfo (see
          Appendix A.2.4) with the DER, where the type DigestInfo has
          the syntax

               DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
                   digestAlgorithm AlgorithmIdentifier,
                   digest OCTET STRING
               }

          The first field identifies the hash function and the second
          contains the hash value.  Let T be the DER encoding of the
          DigestInfo value (see the notes below), and let tLen be the
          length in octets of T.

      3.  If emLen < tLen + 11, output "intended encoded message length
          too short" and stop.

      4.  Generate an octet string PS consisting of emLen - tLen - 3
          octets with hexadecimal value 0xff.  The length of PS will be
          at least 8 octets.

      5.  Concatenate PS, the DER encoding T, and other padding to form
          the encoded message EM as

             EM = 0x00 || 0x01 || PS || 0x00 || T.

      6.  Output EM.
```

Extracting the relevant bits from the X.509 cert isn't the easiest thing to do either.

Comment: I have already extracted all the required data from X.509.